# Update the model object before use UpdateModel() Does not working

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to update the model object with some values before use `UpdateModel` function but update is not working.

```
var sectionEntity = _db.luSections.FirstOrDefault(lu => lu.SectionKey == section.SectionKey);
sectionEntity.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
sectionEntity.LastModifiedBy = Guid.Empty;
sectionEntity.ParentKey = section.ParentKey;

UpdateModel(sectionEntity);

var effectedRows = _db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Try to use debugger... Take into account all the constraints of the underlying db.

Comment: What does _"update is not working"_ mean. Is an exception thrown?

Comment: it is not exception but the model object still with the old values

Comment: What does `sectionEntity` class look like? What does `UpdateModel` do? Which properties that are not updated? Is there any property that got updated?